# Number of solutions of $100x+10y+z=5xyz$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find the number of solutions to the equation $$100x+10y+z=5xyz$$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(1 \le x \le 9)$, $(0 \le y \le 9)$, $(0 \le z \le 9)$.

I have found one solution using a brute-force computer program, but I've been wondering if it's possible to find the number of solutions without checking all possible triplets.

Comment: Well, $5\,|\,z$ so you just have to consider $z=0$ and $z=5$.  $z=0$ is trivial, so you just need to consider $z=5$.

Comment: I assume that the solution you found was $(1, 7, 5)$?

Comment: @Dan Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @janq0 Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24100x%2B10y%2Bz%3D5xyz%24&p=1), there's the related [Number theory - Find the number satisfying the condition.](/q/2882766). However, for your particular question, I suggest first using [lulu's comment](/questions/4695185/number-of-solutions-of-100x10yz-5xyz#comment9934554_4695185) before trying anything else suggested in that question or answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do arithmetic modulo 5, then all the multiple-of-5 terms ($100x$, $10y$, and $5xyz$) cancel out and you're left with just $z = 0$ (mod 5).  IOW, $z$ is a multiple of 5.  There are two cases to deal with:

$$z = 0 \implies 100x+10y=0$$
$$z = 5 \implies 100x+10y+5=25xy$$

For the first case, $100x+10y=0$ is equivalent to $y = -10x$.  So $y$ must be a multiple of 10, and the only in-range one is $y = 0$.  But this gives us $x = 0$, which contradicts the given constraint $1 \le x \le 9$.  So any solutions with $z = 0$ are ruled out.

For the $z = 5$ case, solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ gives:

$$y = \frac{20x+1}{5x-2}$$

Or equivalently,

$$y = 4 + \frac{9}{5x-2}$$

So in order for $y$ to be an integer, we must have $5x - 2$ be a divisor of 9.  IOW, one of the following:

- $5x - 2 = -9 \implies x = -1.4$
- $5x - 2 = -3 \implies x = -0.2$
- $5x - 2 = -1 \implies x = 0.2$
- $5x - 2 = 1 \implies x = 0.6$
- $5x - 2 = 3 \implies x = 1$
- $5x - 2 = 9 \implies x = 2.2$

Only one of these results in an integer: $x = 1$, from which $y = \frac{21}{3} = 7$.  Therefore, the only valid all-integer solution is:

$$\boxed{x = 1, y = 7, z  = 5}$$

Comment: Note that $y$ is an integer and
$$y=\frac{20x+1}{5x-2}=4+\frac{9}{5x-2},$$
so $5x-2$ divides $9$, so $x=1$.

Comment: @Servaes: Good point.  There are only 6 possible divisors of 9 ($\pm\{1, 3, 9\}$), which saves some arithmetic compared to brute-forcing all 9 valid $x$'s, so I've edited my answer to use it.

Comment: Given that $x\geq1$ it is immediate that the only candidate divisors are $3$ and $9$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $z$ is a multiple of $5$ and $z=0$ does not yield a solution, so $z=5$. Then
$$100x+10y+5=25xy.$$
A bit of algebra then shows that
$$(5x-2)(5y-20)=25xy-100x-10y+40=45,$$
and then dividing by $5$ yields
$$(5x-2)(y-4)=9.$$
It follows that $x=1$ and $y=7$.

Comment: Alternatively, remark that (with $z=5$)  we have $2y+1\equiv 0\pmod 5$ so $y\in \{2,7\}$.

Comment: @lulu  Really, I can not see any mathematical reason $z=5k$ implies $z=0\vee z=5$. Putting $z=5k$ doesn't obviously tell me $z=5$. What I am missing ?

Comment: @lonestudent The question specifies that $0\leq z\leq 9$.

Comment: Then, nice answer . (+1)